# SQL Padindex Second position numeric word

Tags: sql-server

I have below query when I was trying to search for second numeric word from the string but didn't get correct results.

```
select right('1111 This is a test 2222 3333', 
             patindex('%[^0-9]%', '1111 This is a test 2222 3333' +'.') - 1)
```

Results should be: 2222

I would appreciate if some one help on this.

Comment: never mind i got it

Comment: In case it helps others, you can post your own code as an answer and accept that answer, you'll get reputation points for it too.

Comment: select substring('1111 This is a test 2222 3333', patindex('%[^0-9][0-9]%', '1111 This is a test 2222 3333' +'.'), 5)